# Apache CXF: JMS connection broken: compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN')

Tags: java, jms, cxf, ibm-mq, jboss6.x

We are facing issue similar to mentioned in [CXF-6778](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6778). In our case our application is deployed on JBOSS EAP 6.4 (which has CXF 2.7.16 bundled inside). We are using IBM WMQ resource adapter as messaging and queuing middleware. JDK version is 1.7.

When MQ server is restarted, our application reconnects to MQ server successfully. But if we try to send any JMS message, we receive following exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
```

We believe that this issue is very much similar to issue mentioned in [CXF-6778](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6778). Issue [CXF-6778](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6778) is claimed to be resolved in release 3.2.0 (not yet released). As version 3.2.0 is yet to be released, we are trying to find out what all options we have.

One option is to upgrade CXF bundled inside JBOSS. But efforts may be high, so we are not planning to do that yet.

Is there any option where we can configure e.g. connection expiry timeout for JMS connection or some other way with which we can remove cached broken connections?

Please note that, if we restart JBOSS server, issue is no more re-producible.

Stacktrace looks like:

```
Runtime exception while getData: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1500.getData(Unknown Source)
        at com.xyz.getData(SomeBean.java:282) [xyz.jar:16.0.1]
        ...
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:431)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSFactory.resolveOrCreateDestination(JMSFactory.java:341) [cxf-rt-transports-jms-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConduit.sendExchange(JMSConduit.java:195) [cxf-rt-transports-jms-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSOutputStream.doClose(JMSOutputStream.java:56) [cxf-rt-transports-jms-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:220) [cxf-api-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56) [cxf-api-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223) [cxf-api-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) [cxf-api-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConduit.close(JMSConduit.java:128)
        ...
        ...
        [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        ... 62 more
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.accessTemporaryQueue(WMQConnection.java:644)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createTemporaryDestination(WMQConnection.java:913)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createTemporaryDestination(WMQSession.java:911)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTemporaryQueueImpl.<init>(JmsTemporaryQueueImpl.java:100)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createTemporaryQueue(JmsSessionImpl.java:1367)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createTemporaryQueue(MQSession.java:758)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.SessionWrapper.createTemporaryQueue(SessionWrapper.java:554)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSFactory$1.doInJms(JMSFactory.java:349) [cxf-rt-transports-jms-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSFactory$1.doInJms(JMSFactory.java:341) [cxf-rt-transports-jms-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
        ... 89 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.getConnection(RemoteSession.java:509)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.isDistListCapable(RemoteSession.java:1826)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQOPEN(RemoteFAP.java:3050)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQOPEN(RemoteFAP.java:2918)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.accessTemporaryQueue(WMQConnection.java:619)
        ... 88 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2202
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:449)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:214)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:105)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:229)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:303)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1241)
```

Answer (score 0):

> JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.

It is one of 2 issues:

- The UserId that is running the J2EE container does not have
  permission to use 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE' when creating a
  temporary or permanent dynamic queue.
- Did someone put 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE' as the actual queue
  name?  'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE' is a model queue and cannot be
  opened.  It is to be used as a model when creating temporary or permanent
  dynamic queues.

Comment: As we are not using permanent destination queue, CXF creates a temporary JMS queue to receive the response. So this is expected behavior. I do not see any issues with access as issue occurs only after MQ server is restarted inbetween. Also we observed that sometimes, when this issue occurs, it occurs only for alternate requests. Remaining alternate requests are processed successfully.

Comment: Well, if it happens after a fail-over then probably the code is using the old connection handle rather than opening a new connection or it could be an authorization failure.  It would be nice to see the MQ completion code and reason code values.

Comment: Yes Roger you are right! Even we believes so. I have already added stack trace in my question. Please let me know, if you need more information. We are almost sure that issue is with CXF library. Please refer to JIRA  CXF-6778 mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to turn off `mqcsp`-Authentication. This can be done with
`ibm.mq.use-authentication-m-q-c-s-p=false`, if you follow IBM's [Spring Boot example](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/) but don't have a password in your configuration.